# Vending Machine - Accept only coins

Tags: c

im doing a vending machine simulator. I need to only accept the real coins like (0.05€ / 0.10€ / 0.20€ etc...) i dont want 0.25€ for example.

code1:

```
if(coin!= 0.05||  coin!= 0.10 || coin!= 0.20 || coin!= 0.50 || coin!= 1 || coin!= 2 )
        printf("It isnt a coin");
    else
        return coin;
```

code2(tryed this too cause of flots):

```
if((aux-0.05 >= 0.001) ||  (aux-0.10 >= 0.0001)||(aux-0.20 >= 0.0001)||(aux-0.50 >= 0.0001)||(aux-1 >= 0000.1)||(aux-2 >= 0000.1))
        printf("It isnt a coin");
    else
        insert_value += aux;
```

neither code 1 or 2 works... the code2 accepts 0.05 coin, but ignore the others

Comment: You need `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: A big tip for future development: Don't represent currency with floating point values unless your application needs to deal with fractional currency.  In euros, for example, the lowest denomination is a 1-cent euro.  Define other denominations in terms of that base denomination using whole numbers.

Comment: @KenoguLabz, regardless of whether you need fractional currency, fixed-point or arbitrary-precision are the most appropriate representations for quantities like currency.  If you need thousandths-of-a-cent precision, then your quantities can represent individual thousandths-of-a-cent.

Comment: @BrianCain You wouldn't create a cash register that was accurate to thousandths of a cent, because all transactions at a register are rounded to whole-cent values.  Consider your domain before making sweeping assumptions.  The vending machine example above is a perfect example of something that only deals in discrete, quantized currency inputs.  Floating-point is designed to approximate a continuum of values, not quantized values that are intended to have very precise meaning.

Comment: Comparing floats for equality is always a bad idea.

Comment: Also, there are many 1-euro coins.

Comment: A 1-euro coin is equivalent to one 100-cent euro coin.

Comment: @KenoguLabz, I believe you didn't read my comment carefully or you misunderstood it.  My comment was in reference to your clause "unless your application needs to deal with fractional currency" [not this vending machine].  My claim is that **even there (when you need to deal with fractional currency)**, you should not use floating-point representation.  While floating-point representation is not linear, it's absolutely representational of discrete values.

Comment: @BrianCain Oh, you are very correct.  I completely misread.  My apologies!

Comment: my application only need to accept all the coin and ignore other values ... i know the problem is with the float values, and i already changed the || to && and stil doesnt work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By declaring an array of acceptable coins, the cash slot on your vending machine can be easily modified to accept 1 or 2 cent coins or a future €5 coin.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int acceptable [] = {5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200};

// return 1 if acceptable coin
int test_coin (int cents) {
    int num_accept = sizeof(acceptable) / sizeof(int);  
    int index;
    for (index=0; index<num_accept; index++)
        if (cents == acceptable[index])
            return 1;
    printf ("Unacceptable coin\n");
    return 0;
    }

int main()
{
    int cents;
    char str [10];
    do {
        printf ("Enter coin value in cents ");
        *str = 0;
        fgets (str, 10, stdin);
        cents = atoi(str);
    } while (!test_coin(cents));
    printf("You inserted %d cents coin\n", cents);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using ANDs, not ORs in your clauses.

For example: `coin != 1 || coin != 2` is *always* true.